# Error in building Tensorflow serving from source

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-serving

I am building Tensorflow serving from source suitable for my CPU. I am using release branch 1.14 and Bazel version 0.26.1.
 I use the following command to build it :

```
tools/run_in_docker.sh bazel build --copt=-mavx2 --copt=-mfma --local_resources=2048,.5,1.0 tensorflow_serving/...
```

I am using MacOS Mojave with 8GB RAM.
ERROR:

```
/Users/user/PycharmProjects/serving/.cache/_bazel_user/28517966d062a7dca9cfa7e5166bc7fc/external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/core/kernels/BUILD:5341:1: C++ compilation of rule '@org_tensorflow//tensorflow/core/kernels:training_ops' failed (Exit 4)
gcc: internal compiler error: Killed (program cc1plus)
Please submit a full bug report,
with preprocessed source if appropriate.
See <file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-7/README.Bugs> for instructions.
INFO: Elapsed time: 1399.895s, Critical Path: 100.48s
INFO: 101 processes: 101 local.
FAILED: Build did NOT complete successfully
```

I am struggling with this for quite some time. Any help in this regard would be helpful.

I used the following [Tutotial](https://github.com/tensorflow/serving/blob/master/tensorflow_serving/g3doc/setup.md)

Comment: Any update? I'm having the same issue w/ Mac OS Catalina. 16GB Ram.

Comment: I was able to get this to work by increasing the amount of RAM that Docker Engine has allocated. I was using the defaults (2GB). Everything worked once I increased to 4GB.

Answer (score 0):

Specifying the Solution here (in Answer Section) even though it is present in Comments Section, for the benefit of the Community.

The problem is resolved by increasing the amount of RAM that Docker Engine has allocated from 2 GB to 4 GB.